# randomly generated probability game with loops and elimination

Tags: c++, loops, random, probability

Here is my assignment:

---

In the land of Puzzlevania, Aaron, Bob, and Charlie had an argument over which one of them
was the greatest puzzle-solver of all time. To end the argument once and for all, they agreed
on a duel to the death. Aaron was a poor shot and only hit his target with a probability of
1/3. Bob was a bit better and hit his target with a probability of 1/2. Charlie was an ex-
pert marksman and never missed. A hit means a kill and the person hit drops out of the duel.
To compensate for the inequities in their marksmanship skills, the three decided that they
would re in turns, starting with Aaron, followed by Bob, and then by Charlie. The cycle
would repeat until there was one man standing. That man would be remembered for all
time as the Greatest Puzzle-Solver of All Time.

An obvious and reasonable strategy is for each man to shoot at the most accurate shooter still
alive, on the grounds that this shooter is the deadliest and has the best chance of hitting back.
Write a program to simulate the duel using this strategy. Your program should use random
numbers and the probabilities given in the problem to determine whether a shooter hits his
target. You will likely want to create multiple subroutines and functions to complete the
problem.

Hint
Let's say Aaron's chance of hitting a target is 1/3. You can simulate this probability by
generating a random variable R between 1 and 99 inclusive. What is the probability that
R is less than 33? It's 1/3. Do you see where this is leading? If R  33, then we can
simulate Aaron hitting a target. If R > 33, then he misses. You can also generate a random
variable between 0 and 1 and check if it is less than 0.33.

---

here is the code i was finally able to work up after rewriting from scratch twice:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;


int main ()
{
    int aaron=1, bob=1,charlie=1, a=0,b=0,c=0,counter=0;
    srand(time(0));
    a= rand() % 100;
    if (a<=33)//if aaron kills charlie
    {
        charlie=0;

        b= rand() % 100; //bob choots at aaron
        if (b<=50)  //if bob kills aaron
        {
            aaron=0;
            cout<<"error1"<<endl;
        }
        else if (b>50)
        {
            while (b>50) //if bob misses
            {
                a= rand() % 100; //aaron shoots at bob
                if (a<=33)// if he kills bob
                {
                    bob=0;
                    cout<<"error2"<<endl;
                }
                else //if he misses
                {
                    b= rand() % 100;//bob shoots at aaron

                    if (b<=50)//if he kills him
                    {
                        aaron=0;
                        cout<<"error3"<<endl;
                    }
                    else //if he misses then the loop continues
                    {
                        counter++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else if (a>33)//aaron misses
    {
        b= rand() % 100; //bob shoots at charlie
        if (b<=50) //he kills charlie
        {
            charlie = 0;
            a= rand() % 100; //aaron shoots at bob
            if (a<=33)//aaron kills bob
            {
                bob=0;
                cout<<"error4"<<endl;
            }
            else //if not
            {
                b= rand() % 100;//bob shoots at aaron
                if (b<=50) // if he kills aaron
                {
                    aaron=0;
                    cout<<"error5"<<endl;
                }
                else if (b>50)
                {
                    while (b>50)//if not then begin loop
                    {
                        a= rand() % 100; //aaron shoots at bob
                        if (a<=33) //if he kills him
                        {
                            bob=0;
                            cout<<"error6"<<endl;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            b= rand() % 100;;   //if not bob shoots at aaron
                            if (b<=50)// if he kills aaron
                            {
                                aaron=0;
                                cout<<"error7"<<endl;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                counter++; //if not loop around
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        else //he misses so charlies kills bob
        {
            bob=0;
            a= rand() % 100; //aaron shoots at charlie
            if (a<=33) //aaron kills charlie
            {
                charlie=0;
                cout<<"error8"<<endl;
            }
            else // or charlie kills aaron
            {
                aaron=0;
                cout<<"error9"<<endl;
            }
        }


        if (charlie==0 && bob==0)
        {
            cout<<"Aaron wins."<<endl;
        }
        else if (aaron==0 && bob==0)
        {
            cout<<"Charlie wins."<<endl;
        }
        else if (charlie==0 && aaron==0)
        {
            cout<<"Bob wins."<<endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I added in the cout line with the error# for when i compile the program to see where my errors are.

the program runs hoever if i get the cout lines of error1,2,3 and 6 i do not get a cout with a named winner that should come with it. furthermore with those numbers i seem to sometimes get a double result (i.e. a result with that error and another one from a different part of the program) leading me to assume there is a problem with my loop(s).

I opted to use a loop instead of a recursive function as it was outside the scope of the assignment.

I would appreciate any review of my syntax and form as I am truly stumped.

Comment: SideNote: If you're supposed to have uniform distribution, you may want to opt for using a uniform distribution RNG algorithm. If you can use C++11, there is such a distribution already provided for you in `<random>`, namely [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution). Kind of odd to setup, but worth it in the end. Just so you know, `rand()%100` will *not* give you a uniform distribution.

Comment: Also, `rand () % 100` gives values in 0..99, not 1..99 as the question seems to demand, so even if the distribution were uniform the `<=33` would give 34% of the cases. `rand () % 3 == 0` would be much more accurate in this case - avoiding that extra 1% and reducing but not eliminating the error from using `%` (clue - the range of random numbers probably isn't divisible by either 3, or 100, or 99 so lower value remainders occur slightly more often).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First point - `a= rand() % 100;` doesn't give 1..99 inclusive, it gives 0..99 inclusive. You could use `a = (rand() % 99) + 1` instead. That's still not a perfectly uniform distribution because the range of random numbers given by `rand` probably isn't divisible by 99. Possible fixes include...

1. Use the C++11 random number library as WhozCraig suggests.
2. Generate random numbers in a loop. If `rand()` gives a value `>= 9900`, for example, throw it away and try again. Put this loop in a function so you don't have to worry about it every time.
3. Don't worry about it - for something like this, if you're supposed to care about the problem, you'd probably have already been warned about it.

Next point is for code such as...

```
if (b<=50)  //if bob kills aaron
{
    aaron=0;
    cout<<"error1"<<endl;
}
else if (b>50)
```

The `if (b>50)` here is completely redundant, at least to the compiler. You might include it for clarity given that you've got a fairly long chunk of code with some deep nesting here, but I'd make it a comment, and let the `else` do its job.

Probably your real problem, though...

```
while (b>50) //if bob misses
{
    a= rand() % 100; //aaron shoots at bob
    if (a<=33)// if he kills bob
    {
        bob=0;
        cout<<"error2"<<endl;
    }
    else //if he misses
    {
        b= rand() % 100;//bob shoots at aaron

        if (b<=50)//if he kills him
        {
            aaron=0;
            cout<<"error3"<<endl;
        }
        else //if he misses then the loop continues
        {
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

If Aaron shoots Bob, `b` is unmodified, so the loop repeats again. Aaron can shoot Bob over and over before finally he misses, and Bob finally gets a turn even though he's already dead. You need to change your loop condition - probably in other cases too, though I haven't checked. I'd probably use a `done` flag.

Next, you don't really need separate variables for `a` and `b` (and I don't think you're even using `c`) - just use a single variable `r` for `random` or similar.

Finally, the structure I'd use would be...

```
while num_alive > 1
  if aaron_alive
    if charlie_alive
      aaron tries to shoot charlie
    else
      aaron tries to shoot bob

  if bob_alive
    if charlie_alive
      bob tries to shoot charlie
    else
      bob tries to shoot aaron

  if charlie_alive
    if bob_alive
      charlie tries to shoot bob
    else
      charlie tries to shoot aaron
```

The point here is that if you try to remember too much about who's alive and who's dead in the control flow, the code gets convoluted. Checking again on the next iteration seems like unnecessary work, but those checks are trivial, and even if they weren't that's premature optimization. You should prefer the simpler code.

In this case, you could also look at how similar those three `if <whoever>_alive` blocks are, and how they might be factored into a function.